# Writing a string to a file goes to the wrong spot

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes a csv file and adds a string to it. The only issue is the string that I add is at the end of the string. I would like it to be in the front of the string instead of the end.

Here is the script:

```
#Adding string to the front of each line for the Part Numbers
string_to_add = r"V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ "

#Open the file and join the .JPG to the current lines
with open("PartNumbers.csv", 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add,'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

with open("PartNumbers.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

It gives me this output:

```
X00TB0001V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0003V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0004V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0005V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0006V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0007V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ 
X01BJ0008V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X00TB0001
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0003
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0004
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0005
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0006
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0007
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\ X01BJ0008
```

My original idea was to change around the line

```
file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add,'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]
```

to this:

```
file_lines = [ string_to_add,''.join([x.strip(),'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]
```

When I do that I get this error:

```
file_lines = [string_to_add,''.join([x.strip(), '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: did you forget parentheses around the comprehension target?
```

How can I edit this script to get the desired output?

Comment: `file_lines = [''.join([string_to_add, x.strip(),'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]`?

Comment: The `strip` and `'\n'` are not really necessary in that case... It can just be `file_lines = [string_to_add + x for x in f]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the x.strip and the string_to_add:

`file_lines = [''.join([string_to_add, x.strip(),'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]`

Comment: The `strip` and `'\n'` are not really necessary in that case...

Answer (score 1):

Just try switching the parameters

```
file_lines = [''.join([string_to_add, x.strip(),'\n']) for x in f.readlines()]
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The `strip` and `'\n'` are not really necessary in that case...